# Why is my focus/blur event listener not triggering?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong or funky here, but it just won't trigger what-so-ever...

```
const elm = (this.agGridElm.nativeElement as HTMLElement);
elm.addEventListener('focus', (focusEvent: FocusEvent) => {
  elm.classList.add('focused');
}, { capture: true, passive: true });

elm.addEventListener('blur', (focusEvent: FocusEvent) => {
  elm.classList.remove('focused');
}, { capture: true, passive: true });
```

I tried with or without the 3rd argument `{ capture: true, passive: true }` and the result is the same... The weird thing is, I could see my listeners being registered when I observe in Chrome debugger's `Event Listeners`, clicking on my element, I could see both `focus` and `blur` were hooked, but just won't trigger.

I did something similar with `mouseleave` and that worked flawlessly, so what's up with `focus` and `blur`? The block below worked...

```
elm.addEventListener('mouseleave', (mouseEvent: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log('Hi there!');
});
```

Comment: Make sure the event listener is added in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding event listeners manually rather than binding in the HTML? Can you show all relevant code. I would say manually binding event listeners is not *necessarily* wrong, but definitely funky in Angular.

Comment: @KurtHamilton you are right, I will use `(focusin)` and `(focusout)` but the real reason was due to lack of `tabindex`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the reason is because for `focus`, `blur`, `focusin` and `focusout` on `div` element, they require to have a `tabindex` for the focus to work!! The solution is to add the following to the element that I wish to listen.

```
<div tabindex="-1"></div>
```

All my code worked with the `tabindex`!

Comment: Detailed explanation here: https://javascript.info/focus-blur#allow-focusing-on-any-element-tabindex